# Out-of-the-box openSUSE 12.3: Package webkit-sharp-devel not found

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I installed openSUSE 12.3 and now want to install the package `gtk-sharp2-devel`:

```
$ sudo zypper install webkit-sharp-devel
Package 'webkit-sharp-devel' not found.
```

Strange since [a Google request](https://www.google.com/search?q=opensuse%20webkit-sharp-devel) seems to show that this package is not unheard of on openSUSE.

Has the package changed name?

By the way, `sudo zypper search webkit | grep devel` does not return any sharp-related result, even though package `webkit-sharp` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for webkit-sharp-devel on [software.opensuse.org](http://software.opensuse.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webkit-sharp-devel&search_devel=false&search_unsupported=false&baseproject=openSUSE%3A12.3), which lists all official packages, returns no result. Which leads me to the cobnclusion, that there is no such package in opensuse 12.3. The newarest hit is [webkit-sharp](http://software.opensuse.org/package/webkit-sharp?search_term=webkit-sharp).